# Does google wallet reponse return the tax deduted?

Tags: android, google-checkout

I am using google wallet in my android app to purchase credits. Google deducts tax based on the country. i would like to get the tax deducted in response on successful payment. Also can anyone let me know what all information can we get in response once the payment is successful?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The financial information you are looking for is available in the "Earnings report" in the new Wallet Merchant Center:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3039702?hl=en